# setOnClickListener is returning a null exception

Tags: android

In my android app I have a page that contains and expandable list with headings and sub items. What I am trying to do is click on one of the sub items and have a new dialog show up. Right now I am getting a null exception on the on click listener but I feel like I have everything set up correctly. Here is the code:

```
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(curriculum_description);
        dialog.setTitle("Description");

        curriculumExpandable = findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
        curriculumExpandable.setOnClickListener(v -> dialog.show());
```

this is the xml I am calling

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/curriculumInfo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

curriculumExpandable is a TextView and expandedListItem is the id of the sub item in the expanded list which is also a TextView. When that sub item is clicked, it should go to the xml shown.

Comment: Please add the error logs

Comment: You're not calling `findViewById()` on an explicit object, there, so presumably it's being called on the `Activity`. Instead, you need to call `findViewById()` on your item `View`, after you've inflated it. If you need specific code, please [edit] your question to show your `Adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where you declared the views.
You might get null exceptions if the view wasn't created by the time you called onClickListener.

for example setting onClickListener inside a fragment's OnCreateView might cause null exceptions.

One more thing you might want to consider adding null checks incase the view wasn't 
created by the time you set the listener on it like this:

```
curriculumExpandable?.setOnClickListener(v -> dialog.show());
```